# import kivy returns an error in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I just installed kivy using the command line as instructed in the kivy site but when i run this code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class HelloWorld(App):

    def build(self):
    return Label(text="hello world")

HelloWorld = HelloWorld()

HelloWorld.run()
```

it returns this error:

```
C:\Users\OnlyMe\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/OnlyMe/PycharmProjects/kivy/kivytut.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/OnlyMe/PycharmProjects/kivy/kivytut.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

I searched for answers on this site as well as googling it but it does not seem relevant on this current version of Kivy.

Any help will do. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In what python have you installed kivy ?, according to the error message pycharm is using the python that is in "C:\Users\OnlyMe\PycharmProjects\kivy\venv\Scripts\python.exe"

Comment: Not really sure on where but I installed it using the instructions on site using cmd but I only have 1 version of python installed. Sorry I'm still learning

Comment: Could you tell me how you installed kivy?

Comment: These are the commands I run:

Comment: What is the PATH of the only python you have installed?

Comment: python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools; python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.angle; python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer; python -m pip install kivy; I just put semicolon on each command that I run

Comment: the path are these: C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\OnlyMe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\

Comment: see this page in section **Working on the same project on different platforms** https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html 
and change the path of the selected python

Comment: Sorry but it still returns the same error even though kivy is under the folder of the specified python interpreter. Or should I make a symbolic link from kivy to the python.exe as specified in other answers in this site?